# Unable to deserialize Json string to POJO (using GSON)

Tags: json, gson, deserialization

Any idea why the JSON won't map to the java object?

The code..

```
String result = "{\"outerclass\":{\"innerclass\":{\"booleanA\":true,\"stringB\":\"b\",\"stringC\":\"c\"}}}\n";

Gson gson = new Gson();
TempObject o = gson.fromJson(result,TempObject.class);
```

The POJO..

```
  public class TempObject {

     public static class outerclass {

      public static class innerclass {

       public static boolean booleanA;
       public static String stringB;
       public static String stringC;

      }    

     }

    }
```

OTher example..

```
String result = "{\"idata\":{\"result\":{\"error\":true,\"errorMessage\":\"Invalid username and/or password\",\"requestTime\":\"2011-08-26T18:39:02Z\"}}}"; 
Gson gson = new Gson();
UserData d = gson.fromJson(result, UserData.class);
```

Class..

```
public class UserData {

    idata data;

    public static class idata {
        result res;

        public static class result {

            public boolean error;
            public String errorMessage;
            public String requestTime;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: What error or failure do you get?

Comment: No error message. o is empty, and o.outerclass.innerclass.stringB returns null

Comment: Hmm, everything looks all right. You should probably try to compile the code (as written above) and ensure that there isn't any minor typo somewhere in your real code. Maybe drop the \n at the end of your string, it serves no purpose.

Comment: I added the \n because the real JSON Response from an external API has the linebreak at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, that's because all of your fields are static, those not related to each separate object.

So I think the class should look like that:

```
public class TempObject {

    Outerclass outerclass;

    public static class Outerclass {
        Innerclass innerclass;

        public static class Innerclass {

            public boolean booleanA;
            public String stringB;
            public String stringC;
        }    
    }
}
```

For example, on my machine, the output of:

```
public class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String result = "{\"outerclass\":{\"innerclass\":{\"booleanA\":true,\"stringB\":\"b\",\"stringC\":\"c\"}}}\n";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        TempObject o = gson.fromJson(result, TempObject.class);
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(o));
    }

    public static class TempObject {

        Outerclass outerclass;

        public static class Outerclass {
            Innerclass innerclass;

            public static class Innerclass {

                public boolean booleanA;
                public String stringB;
                public String stringC;
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Is:

```
{"outerclass":{"innerclass":{"booleanA":true,"stringB":"b","stringC":"c"}}}
```

Comment: That didn't work. TempObject initializes, but outerClass is null. I've tried many variations of static/public/private and pulling the classes from inner classes into separate ones. There's gotta be something basic about gson that I'm missing?

Comment: The code I added (edited a bit to match upper-lower-case) works perfectly for me. See edit.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. For you, it populates all the variables into o? Mine compiles and runs without error, but doesn't actually do anything to o.

Comment: See edit, just for convenience I moved the TempObject class to be an inner class, I got the same results without doing so.

Comment: OK this example does work for me, but when I change nothing but the class/variable names and input strings, it doesn't work anymore.... In my original post I added the actual class and code that I am trying to use. Is there something funky about any of the variable names or values that is causing the issue?

Comment: if you change the variable name, then it is not mapped to the variable anymore. each key is the variable name, not the class name.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to deserialize because the variable names are not matching with the keys in your Json. In your second example

```
String result = "{\"idata\":{\"result\":{\"error\":true,\"errorMessage\":\"Invalid username and/or password\",\"requestTime\":\"2011-08-26T18:39:02Z\"}}}"; 

idata data;
result res;
```

The object names should match with the keys in JSON but not class names.

IData **idata**;
Result **result**;